# 100 bonus reputation from trusted site not enough to answer protected question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

I found this question on Google:

[Loop without 'looping'](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/33196/loop-without-looping)

And I thought it was very interesting. So I came up with my own answer and signed up for codegolf.stackexchange

Because I have almost 6000 reputation on stackoverflow, I was awarded with 100 reputation points.

But the question mentioned above is protected, and says that I need at least 10 reputation points to answer.

Is reputation awarded like this not count towards things like this?

Comment: No, the 100 starting rep don't count towards protected questions.

Comment: You are correct m.buettner. I'll vote to close as dupe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message says you need to earn at least 10 reputation **on the site you are posting on**.

The association bonus doesn't count.